# Alfresco Activiti - How get attachment id in alfresco activiti?

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti

This is json code for the form of upload file

```
"fieldType":"AttachFileFieldRepresentation",
      "id":"upload_file",
       "name":"Upload source project (project folder or zip file)",
       "type":"upload",
```

And in a method inside a execution listener class I created I have this code

```
 taskService = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine().getTaskService(); 
    Attachment attach = taskService.getAttachment("upload_file");
 if(attach!=null){
   System.out.println("Attachment not null");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Null file attached");
         }
```

Every time I get a **null file**.

I am not able to retrieve the file uploaded.
I don't know what I am doing wrong
Can you please help me how get the attachment?

Comment: try - `getTaskAttachments(String taskId)` method from TaskService  to get All Attachments of a task.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code may help you for getting the attachment ids.

```
ActivitiScriptNode scriptNode = (ActivitiScriptNode)execution.getVariable(WorkflowNotificationUtils.PROP_PACKAGE);              
NodeRef packagenode = scriptNode.getNodeRef();
NodeRef docRef= Configuration.serviceRegistry.getNodeService().getChildAssocs(packagenode).get(0).getChildRef();
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need little more help. Like, how to get attachment id. String attachment_id = ......//how to get it here